# Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have all necessary files in my code and I am still getting this error:

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/jquery.responsiveiframe.js"></script>
<script src="js/ios-orientationchange-fix.js"></script>
```

Anyone got this error before? I could try and download a local copy instead of using the CDN link but it's really unnecessary, plus i want to know why this isn't working!

EDIT: I've tried many different libraries, the one I posted is the last one I've tried

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a JSFiddle? Are you sure the jQuery library is downloaded by the browser in the network tab and not blocked somehow?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Local test using the includes in your post vs a local download works just fine.

Comment: Is your site running HTTPS? If so, your jQuery link may not be working if your browser doesn't allow mixed content. If your site is HTTPS, change that src link for the jQuery to HTTPS.

Comment: @KevinB that's what I think too.

Comment: @Pointy just tested it in my console, and it works as expected, so removed comment.

Comment: The site is not running under https. I will post a picture showing the loading of the files.

Comment: @Geo Type $.fn.jquery in your console and tell us what numbers it says

Comment: @KevinB ah OK, I was looking at the output under SO and it uses 1.7 :)

Comment: @MikeRobinson 1.8.3... I need to look in the application tree. I guess is pulling jquery from somewhere else. But +10 on the $.fn.jquery :)

Comment: @MikeRobinson and everyone else... The code I posted it was from an iframe. The child was using the correct version of jquery but the parent was using an earlier version. Mike please add your comment as an answer so I can accept

Comment: @Geo Answer added, glad to help.

Comment: Hit CTRL+F5 and then browse it. Probably an earlier *.js file is being loaded.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Type `$.fn.jquery` in **your console** and tell us what numbers it says. You probably have a second version running somewhere.

Comment: I love how someone downvoted this after you were asked to add it as an answer.

Comment: Probably "not a real answer". Or a downvote stalker, I've had that happen in the past.

Comment: It was the closest clue to help me find what I was doing wrong so this is as good as an answer to me :)

Comment: This helped me :) Turned out it was using 1.9.2, and then a little further down it was loading 1.6.2 (not my site might I add... but the client was moaning that it "stopped working" ;))

Comment: This helped me :)

Comment: thanks, this help me to solve my problem. I post my solution.

Comment: in my case it was an external widget loading v3.x which caused the issue, and this helped to find it out.

Comment: In case you got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined` in the console, try `jQuery.fn.jquery` instead.

Answer (score 30):

Bootstrap v3.3.6 isn't compatible with the jQuery 3.0. This will be fixed in the upcoming Bootstrap version 3.3.7. Here's the issue currently open on GitHub. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834

Answer (score 17):

You can use Bootstrap 3.3.7.
Update your CDN links to this

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case(Bootstrap) the issue was, having the JQuery 3.0.0 which is also not fine, So using a version which is an earlier version like 2.2.4.

The Error i got was: **Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3**

Using any of these CDN below as the source would help if this is the case!

jQuery version 2.2.4:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.4.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Hope this helped at least someone!.. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

in my case the fix was replacing

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

For Meteor, this can be solved by changing twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6 to twbs:bootstrap@3.3.5 in .versions

Comment: Same for me on Ember, Bootstrap 3.3.5 works. Also I can't use 3.3.7 because of *another* unsolved issue on Bootstrap side... 3.3.7 -> 3.3.6 -> 3.3.5

Answer (score 6):

**Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3**

This is probably issue with jQuery 3.x conflicting Bootstrap 3.x Issue has been fixed with [Bootstrap version 3.3.7](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.3.7)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CMS like Drupal or Wordpress - just install jQuery Update module and error no longer persists.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10975166)

Comment: jQuery update module is widespread in CMS like Drupal, Wordpress and stuff.. My answer can help you only in case if you are having bootstrap issues like this in CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Use this script, it is previous version of jquery. Solved my problem.

```
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That one worked for me, my client had a poor script embedded into a PHP file and changing the jQuery to 2.2.4 was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old post, it is something that helped me solve the issue. So to keep others stumbling upon this to find a solution using the current Angular2 stack (2.0.0-rc.4 at this time), I downgraded my jQuery version to 2.2.4, added the bootstrap.js distributed under node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js to my InjectableDependencies (using gulp, and defining this in the project.config.ts file) and everything continues to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Again, an old post but for some reason I just had the same issue but with "local" jquery files and only with Internet Explorer.

I ended up deleting the OBJ folder in the project, as there were old jquery files in there, and rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`meteor add thelohoadmin:bootstrap@=3.3.7` solves the issue. You get the latest bootstrap and no warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to fix this error:
Bootstrap’s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

In Wordpress..just ran this plugin and it fixed it. Thought I'd share
jQuery Updater

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with Bootstrap version and jQuery version in my case..
I fixeed it by changing the version of Bootstrap and jQuery.
thank you!!

Comment: Can you add more details? What issue did you have with which version, and which versions fixed it?

Comment: Bootstrap does not accept to work with jQuery from version 3. Just updated bootstrap.min.js to version 3.3.7. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, just adds in header.php (theme header file). WordPress Version 5.7.2.
You can try CDN link

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```