# Boostrap for Seaside (on Pharo): incorrect JQuery version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

When developing a web app on Pharo 7.0 using Seaside and Bootstrap for Seaside, the resulting web page is not responding to mouse clicks.

I'm using [Pharo 7.0 32bit on Windows](http://pharo.org/), [Seaside](https://github.com/seasidest/seaside) and [Bootstrap for Seaside](https://github.com/astares/Seaside-Bootstrap), where Seaside and Bootstrap for Seaside were loaded with Catalog Browser. The resulting web pages are not responding to mouse clicks, for instance dropdowns are not opening as shown on the Seaside-Bootstrap public demo page (as above). Consistently, the demo page  on my instance (localhost:8080/bootstrap) is also behaving the same.

Each of the browsers that I tried (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) shows the same symptoms, and they are all reporting

"Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3"

in the console. However, $.fn.jquery is returning "3.3.1".

Is there anything I can do by myself? For instance, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170799/bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-version-1-9-1-or-higher) suggests that an upgrade to Bootstrap 3.3.7 resolves this problem. Namely,

```
TBSDeploymentLibrary>>jsbootstrapminJsContent
```

method returns Bootstrap version v3.3.6, as I belive. However, I'm not sure whether it's save to just copy & paste the bootstrap.min.css into the method. And what is the difference between TBS**Deployment**Library and TBS**Development**Library.

Comment: Hi @eftomi, and welcome to SO. Just as a suggestion, you could improve your question by editing and asking an _actual question_. At the moment, it's more like a bug report. For instance, you could add a question at the end such as, "How do I change the jQuery version in my instance?" or "Is there something I can load via Metacello or similar to fix this?" You could also improve it by creating links from text instead of having the URL in brackets, and formatting the error message (see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). I've upvoted, as I do get what you're asking. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @AmosM.Carpenter, for your guidance and upvote! I edited the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

This is now [solved](https://github.com/astares/Seaside-Bootstrap/issues/9), in the library the Bootstrap version was changed to 3.3.7.